# Oracle stored function takes more time to retrieve data

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-functions

My development environment is dotNet and c#. DB is Oracle.Currently from the c# code, i'm executing some inline queries. The query is executed using the command

```
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The data is retrieved using

```
rdr.Read()
```

It takes around 300ms to execute the first statement and 100 ms to execute the second statement. Now i've created a new oracle stored function and the same result set is being returned as a cursor. In this case, the ExecuteReader() statement takes around 300ms, but the rdr.Read() statement takes around 800ms to retrieve the same resultset.Can anyone please tell me why this happens?

Comment: What are the two queries?  What are the two query plans?  How many rows are returned?  Without seeing any code, we're pretty much blind.  Perhaps the function is implemented poorly.

Comment: query is just a select statement. It returns only 2 rows.The function is also a simple one. It contains just this select query and returns the resultset as a cursor

Comment: Are the query plans identical?  Again, without seeing any code, we're pretty much blind.  Have you traced the session?  What are the wait events?